# efficient way finding pair value in adjacent columns (Python/R/Sql)

Tags: python, r, algorithm, data-structures

I have a dataframe(*df* below) in pandas with several million rows * 20 columns.

And given a pair of values, I'm trying to find if they exist in adjacent columns of *df*.

e.g.
***df*** looks like

[image]

Given pairs of value **(a3, b2)**, we find they exist in adjacent columns(doesn't have to be in the same row).

For pairs of value **(b2, a3)**, we don't consider they meet the condition(the shift of column should be to the right).

This can be done using loops for a small dataset, but I have millions of records with 20 columns and lots of pairs to check. Is there any way to compute this efficiently? 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for SQL solution or a pandas solution?

Comment: Either is OK. As long as the computation is efficient enough on both time and memory.

Comment: Pandas is a python library.  Just to be clear, are you trying to find a solution in python or in R ?

Comment: If you want a SQL solution, please let us know which database you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear. I'm currently working in python using pandas, but if there's a better option in Sql or R, that would be good too.

Comment: Hi @GMB, I'm using SQL server

Answer (score 3):

Using `df`in ThomasIsCoding's post, here is an option using `data.table` in R:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(VAL=unlist(df), COL=rep(1L:ncol(df), each=nrow(df)), key="VAL")
isadj <- function(left, right) {
    DT[.(left), .(COL=COL+1L)][DT[.(right)], on=.(COL), nomatch=0L, .N > 0L]
}

isadj("a3", "b2")    
#[1] TRUE

isadj("b2", "a3")    
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Great answer with `data.table`, + 1! But I suspect building `DT` is super expensive especially when having a large data frame as described by OP. I added a benchmark in my answer so you could check it out

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution by defining a function `isAdjacent`

```
isAdjacent <- function(df,p) {
    colnum <- col(df)
    diff(sapply(p,function(x) colnum[df==x],USE.NAMES = FALSE))==1
}
```

where `df` is the data.frame, and `p` is the pair.

**Example**

```
p1 <- c("b1","c2")
p2 <- rev(p1)
p3 <- c("a1","c3")

> isAdjacent(df,p1)
[1] TRUE

> isAdjacent(df,p2)
[1] FALSE

> isAdjacent(df,p3)
[1] FALSE
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"), B = c("b1", "b2", 
"b3", "b4"), C = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"), D = c("d1", "d2", 
"d3", "d4"), E = c("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"), F = c("f1", "f2",
"f3", "f4"), G = c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 

-4L))
```

**Large Data Example (Benchmarking)**

```
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(sapply(letters[1:20], paste0, 1:1e6)), LETTERS[1:20])

p <- c("a1", "c3")
system.time({
    isAdjacent <- function(df, p) {
        colnum <- col(df)
        diff(sapply(p, function(x) colnum[df == x], USE.NAMES = FALSE)) == 1
    }
    isAdjacent(df, p)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.03    0.07    1.11

library(data.table)
system.time({
    DT <- data.table(VAL = unlist(df), COL = rep(1L:ncol(df), each = nrow(df)), key = "VAL")
    isadj <- function(left, right) {
        DT[.(left), .(COL = COL + 1L)][DT[.(right)], on = .(COL), nomatch = 0L, .N > 0L]
    }
    isadj(p[1], p[2])
})

#   user  system elapsed
#  35.79    1.91   36.24
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited my data set a little bit just now. apply() functions are succinct comparing with for/while loops, but I still doubt its performance on a large dataset.

Comment: @amon I updated my answer so you can see the performance (the solution by chinsoon12 is alse added for benchmarking)

Comment: I think that's because chinsoon12 handled multiple occurrences of the same value.  I was doing similar things in pandas and the performance is not good either.